# Is it possible to pattern detect within a Window object?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

To give you a bit of context what I'm trying to achieve with this small example is to detect which stops the bus **didn't stop** after two stops (may not have much sense but it's a simple personal exercise.

Take this DF as an example.

```
val sampleData = Seq(
  ("BUS_1", "2019-04-01T01.00:00.000Z", true, "STOP_1"),
  ("BUS_1", "2019-04-01T01.15:00.000Z", true, "STOP_2"),
  ("BUS_1", "2019-04-01T01.20:00.000Z", true, "STOP_3"),
  ("BUS_1", "2019-04-01T01.24:00.000Z", false, "STOP_4"),
  ("BUS_1", "2019-04-01T01.25:00.000Z", false, "STOP_5"),
  ("BUS_1", "2019-04-01T01.26:00.000Z", false, "STOP_6"),
  ("BUS_1", "2019-04-01T01.27:00.000Z", true, "STOP_7"),
  ("BUS_1", "2019-04-01T01.28:00.000Z", false, "STOP_8"),
  ("BUS_1", "2019-04-01T01.29:00.000Z", false, "STOP_9")
)

val df = sampleData.toDF("busId", "timestamp", "stopped", "stopId")
df.show()
```

Which should give the following output.

```
+-----+--------------------+-------+------+
|busId|           timestamp|stopped|stopId|
+-----+--------------------+-------+------+
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01:00:...|   true|STOP_1|
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.15:...|   true|STOP_2|
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.20:...|   true|STOP_3|
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.24:...|  false|STOP_4|
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.25:...|  false|STOP_5|
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.26:...|  false|STOP_6|
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.27:...|   true|STOP_7|
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.28:...|  false|STOP_8|
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.29:...|  false|STOP_9|
+-----+--------------------+-------+------+
```

Now, I would like to detect those that have `"false"` in `"stopped"` Column also saving in that registry the two previous `"true"` stops. After that computation it should look like this.

```
+-----+--------------------+-------+------+--------------------+
|busId|           timestamp|stopped|stopId|            registry|
+-----+--------------------+-------+------+--------------------+
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01:00:...|   true|STOP_1|                null|
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.15:...|   true|STOP_2|                null|
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.20:...|   true|STOP_3|                null|
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.24:...|  false|STOP_4|[STOP_2, STOP_3, STOP_4)|
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.24:...|  false|STOP_5|[STOP_2, STOP_3, STOP_5)|
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.24:...|  false|STOP_6|[STOP_2, STOP_3, STOP_6)|
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.24:...|   true|STOP_7|                null|
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.24:...|  false|STOP_8|                null|
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.24:...|  false|STOP_9|                null|
+-----+--------------------+-------+------+--------------------+
```

I tried to wrap it around a Window the following way.

```
val busWindowExample = Window
  .partitionBy(
    "busId",
  )
  .orderBy(
    "timestamp"
  )
```

So I can send those n-previous values to a UDF which computes the `registry` column like this for example.

`lead(col("stopped"), offset = 4).over(sampleData)`.

However, this has the inconvenience of not being able to track the full previous path, thus missing on `STOP_5` and `STOP_6` since the pattern will be `(true, false, false)` and `(false, false, false)` respectively.

Would there be a way of tracking the whole Window and act in consequence? So that each Row has the context of the whole Window so to say (i.e. each Row knows all of the other Rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you wanted... The key is to use `ignorenulls=True` in the `last` function. Combining that with `when`, you can get the previous row that satisfies a given condition.

```
val w = Window.partitionBy("busId").orderBy("timestamp")

val result = df.withColumn(
    "two_consecutive",
    $"stopped" && lag($"stopped", 1).over(w)
).withColumn(
    "last_consecutive_stop",
    last(when($"two_consecutive", $"stopId"), true).over(w)
).withColumn(
    "last_stop", 
    last(when($"stopped", $"stopId"), true).over(w)
).withColumn(
    "registry",
    when(
        not($"stopped") && ($"last_consecutive_stop" === $"last_stop"),
        concat(
            collect_list(
                when($"two_consecutive", $"stopId")
            ).over(w), 
            array($"stopId")
        )
    )
).drop("two_consecutive", "last_consecutive_stop", "last_stop")

result.show(false)
+-----+------------------------+-------+------+------------------------+
|busId|timestamp               |stopped|stopId|registry                |
+-----+------------------------+-------+------+------------------------+
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.00:00.000Z|true   |STOP_1|null                    |
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.15:00.000Z|true   |STOP_2|null                    |
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.20:00.000Z|true   |STOP_3|null                    |
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.24:00.000Z|false  |STOP_4|[STOP_2, STOP_3, STOP_4]|
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.25:00.000Z|false  |STOP_5|[STOP_2, STOP_3, STOP_5]|
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.26:00.000Z|false  |STOP_6|[STOP_2, STOP_3, STOP_6]|
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.27:00.000Z|true   |STOP_7|null                    |
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.28:00.000Z|false  |STOP_8|null                    |
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.29:00.000Z|false  |STOP_9|null                    |
+-----+------------------------+-------+------+------------------------+
```

Behind the scenes:

```
+-----+------------------------+-------+------+---------------+---------------------+---------+------------------------+
|busId|timestamp               |stopped|stopId|two_consecutive|last_consecutive_stop|last_stop|registry                |
+-----+------------------------+-------+------+---------------+---------------------+---------+------------------------+
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.00:00.000Z|true   |STOP_1|null           |null                 |STOP_1   |null                    |
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.15:00.000Z|true   |STOP_2|true           |STOP_2               |STOP_2   |null                    |
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.20:00.000Z|true   |STOP_3|true           |STOP_3               |STOP_3   |null                    |
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.24:00.000Z|false  |STOP_4|false          |STOP_3               |STOP_3   |[STOP_2, STOP_3, STOP_4]|
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.25:00.000Z|false  |STOP_5|false          |STOP_3               |STOP_3   |[STOP_2, STOP_3, STOP_5]|
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.26:00.000Z|false  |STOP_6|false          |STOP_3               |STOP_3   |[STOP_2, STOP_3, STOP_6]|
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.27:00.000Z|true   |STOP_7|false          |STOP_3               |STOP_7   |null                    |
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.28:00.000Z|false  |STOP_8|false          |STOP_3               |STOP_7   |null                    |
|BUS_1|2019-04-01T01.29:00.000Z|false  |STOP_9|false          |STOP_3               |STOP_7   |null                    |
+-----+------------------------+-------+------+---------------+---------------------+---------+------------------------+
```